# Why am I getting push-back for linking to my own blog posts in answers?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, self-promotion

I posted an answer to a question. It linked to a blog post where I had gone through the answer in detail. What I posted did not seem any different from any number of other answers I have seen on Stack Exchange.

For some reason, someone at Stack Exchange notified me that I was in trouble for doing this. I attempted to find out why my answer was objectionable. The person declined to explain. It seemed that s/he did not bother to see whether the link was relevant to the question; apparently Stack Exchange just assumed I was a spammer.

That was a few weeks back. I was going to try to answer another question, just now, but I received a warning that said, "Some of your past answers have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from answering." And yes, once again, I was going to link to a blog post in which I went through the issue at length.

I suppose I could try to put the full text of the post into my answer here. But I doubt that would go over very well either. The post contains several thousand words.

We all appreciate appropriate efforts to prevent spam. But I have been working with computers for 35 years, and I have posted hundreds of posts during that time. I think my total income from this effort has been about $50. (Yeah, I know, I'm doing something wrong in that department.)

In other words, I don't appreciate being blackballed when my answers are no different from thousands of others: a brief response and a link to some other page that provides more detail.

My apologies in advance if I am putting this in the wrong place, or am missing some other aspect of the situation that should be obvious to me. I was tempted to just say screw it, but I thought others have probably experienced something similar. I tried to figure out where to put this note; this is where I wound up; and I hope something constructive will come of it.

Comment: `-1` for rantiness. That said, could you link to the post in question? Link-only answers are not allowed, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer and doing so to your *own* site without disclosure is considered spam.

Comment: It's been a while since we've had someone invoke [Godwin's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) in the title.

Comment: Nazi? hardly that organized ... just random mobs with wooden sticks

Comment: Links by themselves aren't valid answers. Put content directly in the answer. Supplementary off-site content is nice, but it doesn't make an answer in itself.

Comment: You might be interested to know that deleting your own answers apparently counts against you for the purposes of an answer ban

Comment: ... which I find truly bizarre.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of how long you've been working with computers, or of how little you've earnt financially from doing so. I would also really prefer that you didn't flippantly accuse people of being "Nazis"; that's extremely offensive to those of us whose families were horrific victims of actual Nazis.

Comment: It's worth noting that your blog has been inactive since 2012 so it's hardly as if you're writing blog posts specifically about those questions. I didn't think that was clear in this post.

Comment: 'wooden sticks'??  I have a real, steel pitchfork and a flamethrower.

Comment: So BradleyDotNET illustrates the problem: even those few paragraphs of explanation might be considered "ranty" for purposes of answers here. What if I had included a fuller explanation -- adding, say, the gist of the email exchange, which (for brevity) ended with these unanswered statements from me: "But, again, I was not there for the wrong reasons. And, again, completely answering the question directly in the post was not feasible, as you will see from the length of the post to which I directed you."

Comment: My background is relevant to suggest that I would have nothing to gain from spamming. This is not a case of someone posting dozens of extraneous links. I rarely post on Stack Exchange. I just took a minute to point the prior asker to a post that I thought s/he might find useful. I feel that Stack Exchange overreacted.

Comment: As for Godwin's Law, see Seinfeld's "Soup Nazi." The term gets used in lots of ways -- including humorous ways -- by lots of people, including many among those to whom Lightness Races refers.

On the other point made by Lightness, the blog in question has been active throughout the past several years. But I do not know why that would be relevant.

Answer (score 26):

Kate Gregory offers some good guidelines for linking to off-site content in your posts. [She suggests that...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way/94027#94027)

> - ...you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
> - ...you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
> - ...someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all
> - ...you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile

#### Related:

- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)
- [How to refer to your blog when answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20531/how-to-refer-to-your-blog-when-answering)

Comment: I appreciate these suggestions. This would have been helpful content for the email I received from Stack Exchange. I would have been glad to add another sentence or two, not in a misguided attempt at a "complete" answer, but to convey just a flavor of it, if Stack Exchange had said that was the objective. But see below.

Answer (score 20):

> my answers are no different from thousands of others: a brief response and a link to some other page that provides more detail.

I think this is the core of the problem: you've seen that many people write essentially link-only answers and taken that to mean that link-only answers are acceptable and/or encouraged.

But that is not the case! The only reason that so many link-only answers exist is that so many people misunderstand the purpose of this website, and it is very difficult to keep up with those posts from a moderation standpoint.

In general I suggest reading the help material and taking its contents into account rather than trying to learn the ropes solely from alleged precedents that you might see across the network; for example, you would have found quite quickly that questions *about* Stack Overflow and its policies belong on Meta Stack Overflow.

It sounds like you write extremely long treatments for questions on your blog. That's great! But, ultimately, that is *separate* from whatever contributions you make on Stack Overflow itself, where your answers should be of answer-length and be *self-contained*. You could link to your blog posts and direct anyone there who is interested in a much longer read, but your answer *must* stand alone otherwise.

Thank you for coming here and asking about it so nicely. You are probably not aware that downvotes *on Meta* signal disagreement with a question or proposal, rather than reflecting opinion on the quality of the post itself; so, quite contrary to how it is on Stack Overflow, don't worry about the downvotes you're receiving here. They are simply saying "you're wrong" in this matter, and Shog and I have now explained why that is. :-)

Comment: As noted above, mine was not a link-only answer. So, yes, I was puzzled, not by the rules, but by their irregular enforcement -- coming after me, when there were so many worse examples, and then refusing to clarify when I tried to understand.

And no, I did not find out "quite quickly" that questions about Stack Exchange belong on Meta Stack Overflow. That, again, would have been useful information to include in the single email I received. Instead of treating a would-be helper as someone deserving punishment, it would make more sense to help contributors become better-informed.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for my reaction to all the downvotes. Those are kind words. Yet there is a mixed signal here. Please do not characterize my observation of precedents as merely "alleged" when you, yourself, acknowledge that the precedents exist, and please do not make uncharitable assumptions about the avenues of expression that I would have found if I had looked -- because I did.

Comment: Going back to the original issue and your penultimate paragraph, I understand the part about providing a brief (what you call answer-length) answer. I was very attentive to that. It was not feasible to give what Shog9 calls a "paraphrase" of the possibilities examined in my blog post. I did invite the Stack Exchange emailer to take a look and tell me how I was supposed to achieve that. I do not know why s/he declined to address that question.

Comment: The same is true of your suggestion that it be self-contained. It did seem reasonable to say, Hey, you're asking about X, and I have a post that elaborates on that if you're interested. That is the sort of thing that I, myself, often benefit from, when I see it on Stack Exchange and elsewhere. I don't know why Stack Exchange would want to squelch that sort of communication. Users could simply report offending participants.

Comment: When I say Stack Exchange overreacted (above), I mean that the staffer in question does not seem to have understood, or even tried to understand, the realities of the situation. It would be bad enough to receive a warning based on such ignorance. A threat seemed beyond the pale.

Comment: _"And no, I did not find out 'quite quickly' that questions about Stack Exchange belong on Meta Stack Overflow. That, again, would have been useful information to include in the single email I received."_ My point is that you would have done had you read any of the network's help material. As for the rest of your diatribe, speaking of "overreactions", I think if you acted less sorry-for-yourself writing essays on how mean everyone is every time you feel "wronged", you'd get further. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_  I don't care about this topic enough to respond to all of your points in turn, but I will continue to say "alleged" because without seeing even _one_ of the answers that you're talking about, this is _all_ speculation and you know it.

Comment: Just for posterity: the original title on this topic, when I posted it in Stack Overflow, was "Stack Overflow Nazis." We have now discussed that terminology (e.g., Seinfeld's "Soup Nazi"). This reply from Lightness underscores a certain hostility at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RayWoodcock: Yes, I do get hostile when you refer to me as a member of a group of people who summarily butchered my family. No, I don't understand why you insist on defending your behaviour. You've lost all sympathy from me entirely.

Comment: I guess a person can always invent an excuse for unreasonable behavior. I was impressed with your response to my initial post -- when it actually did have "Nazi" in the heading. But now that you have removed my post to this backwater -- when nobody is looking -- it seems you feel more free to indulge an uglier approach. I'd suggest just staying on point. As detailed above, Stack Exchange handled this matter poorly. Why make yourself part of the problem?

Comment: @Ray I haven't "removed your post" anywhere, and Meta is hardly a "backwater". Just _stop talking_ — you're digging a bigger hole for yourself every time you write another sanctimonious and baffling comment.

Comment: I did not originally post in Meta. Someone moved my post here. So yes, it has been removed to this location. There have been virtually no comments since it was moved here. That qualifies this venue as a backwater. Also, it is now posted under a title that I did not choose, and that does not accurately reflect the issue I presented. These things are clear. I don't think you are baffled. I think you are just continuing to illustrate a certain ineptitude at Stack Exchange. If you are capable of addressing the issues presented, please do. If you are not, at least stop the personal attacks.

Comment: @Ray There have been few comments on this post because it's a pretentious rant, not because of its location. Your insistence on calling out everyone else for being "inept" and blaming _me_ for the post migration shows that you simply do not understand the community that you're moaning about. And, finally, I never attacked _you_; I attacked your behaviour, which belies any claim to the moral high ground that you seem to think you hold. I shan't be responding any further to this entirely pointless and purposeless post. Good luck.